# Implementing contrastive loss function in mxnet

Tags: mxnet, loss-function

I want to train siamese net using depth image obtaining from kinect.I want to use contrastive loss function to train this network, but I'm not find contrastive loss function in mxnet.My implement is as follow:

```
def LossFunc(distance, label, margin):
distance = distance.reshape(label.shape)

dis_positive = distance * label

dis_negative = margin - distance
zeros = nd.zeros(label.shape, ctx=ctx)
dis_negative = nd.concat(dis_negative, zeros, dim=1)
dis_negative = nd.max(dis_negative, axis=1).reshape(label.shape)
dis_negative = (1-label) * dis_negative

return 0.5 * dis_positive**2 + 0.5 * dis_negative**2
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the implementation of the Contrastive loss using [Gluon API](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/index.html#gluon-api):

```
class ContrastiveLoss(Loss):
    def __init__(self, margin=2.0, weight=None, batch_axis=0, **kwargs):
        super(ContrastiveLoss, self).__init__(weight, batch_axis, **kwargs)
        self.margin = margin

    def hybrid_forward(self, F, output1, output2, label):
        euclidean_distance = F.sqrt(F.square(output1 - output2))
        loss_contrastive = F.mean(((1-label) * F.square(euclidean_distance) +
                                      label * F.square(F.clip(self.margin - euclidean_distance, 0.0, 10))))
        return loss_contrastive
```

I have implemented it based on PyTorch example how to use Siamese net taken from [here](https://hackernoon.com/facial-similarity-with-siamese-networks-in-pytorch-9642aa9db2f7).

There are quite some differences in PyTorch and MxNet, so if you want to try this one out, here is the full runnable example. You would need to download the AT&T faces data though and convert images to jpeg as mxnet doesn't support loading .pgm images out of the box.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import autograd
from mxnet.base import numeric_types
from mxnet.gluon import nn, HybridBlock, Trainer
from mxnet.gluon.data import DataLoader
from mxnet.gluon.data.vision.datasets import ImageFolderDataset
from mxnet.gluon.loss import Loss


def imshow(img,text=None, should_save=False):
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.axis("off")
    if text:
        plt.text(75, 8, text, style='italic',fontweight='bold',
            bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'alpha':0.8, 'pad':10})
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))
    plt.show()


def show_plot(iteration, loss):
    plt.plot(iteration, loss)
    plt.show()


class Config:
    training_dir = "./faces/training/"
    testing_dir = "./faces/testing/"
    train_batch_size = 5
    train_number_epochs = 100


class SiameseNetworkDataset(ImageFolderDataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None):
        super().__init__(root, flag=0, transform=transform)
        self.root = root
        self.transform = transform

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        items_with_index = list(enumerate(self.items))
        img0_index, img0_tuple = random.choice(items_with_index)
        # we need to make sure approx 50% of images are in the same class
        should_get_same_class = random.randint(0, 1)
        if should_get_same_class:
            while True:
                # keep looping till the same class image is found
                img1_index, img1_tuple = random.choice(items_with_index)
                if img0_tuple[1] == img1_tuple[1]:
                    break
        else:
            img1_index, img1_tuple = random.choice(items_with_index)

        img0 = super().__getitem__(img0_index)
        img1 = super().__getitem__(img1_index)

        return img0[0].transpose(), img1[0].transpose(), mx.nd.array(mx.nd.array([int(img1_tuple[1] != img0_tuple[1])]))

    def __len__(self):
        return super().__len__()


class ReflectionPad2D(HybridBlock):
    """Pads the input tensor using the reflection of the input boundary.
    Parameters
    ----------
    padding: int
        An integer padding size
    Shape:
        - Input: :math:`(N, C, H_{in}, W_{in})`
        - Output: :math:`(N, C, H_{out}, W_{out})` where
          :math:`H_{out} = H_{in} + 2 * padding
          :math:`W_{out} = W_{in} + 2 * padding
    """
    def __init__(self, padding=0, **kwargs):
        super(ReflectionPad2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if isinstance(padding, numeric_types):
            padding = (0, 0, 0, 0, padding, padding, padding, padding)
        assert(len(padding) == 8)
        self._padding = padding

    def hybrid_forward(self, F, x, *args, **kwargs):
        return F.pad(x, mode='reflect', pad_width=self._padding)


class SiameseNetwork(HybridBlock):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.cnn1 = nn.HybridSequential()
        with self.cnn1.name_scope():
            self.cnn1.add(ReflectionPad2D(padding=1))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Conv2D(in_channels=1, channels=4, kernel_size=3))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Activation('relu'))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.BatchNorm())

            self.cnn1.add(ReflectionPad2D(padding=1))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Conv2D(in_channels=4, channels=8, kernel_size=3))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Activation('relu'))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.BatchNorm())

            self.cnn1.add(ReflectionPad2D(padding=1))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Conv2D(in_channels=8, channels=8, kernel_size=3))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Activation('relu'))
            self.cnn1.add(nn.BatchNorm())

        self.fc1 = nn.HybridSequential()
        with self.fc1.name_scope():
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Dense(500)),
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Activation('relu')),
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Dense(500)),
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Activation('relu')),
            self.cnn1.add(nn.Dense(5))

    def hybrid_forward(self, F, input1, input2):
        output1 = self._forward_once(input1)
        output2 = self._forward_once(input2)
        return output1, output2

    def _forward_once(self, x):
        output = self.cnn1(x)
        #output = output.reshape((output.shape[0],))
        output = self.fc1(output)
        return output


class ContrastiveLoss(Loss):
    def __init__(self, margin=2.0, weight=None, batch_axis=0, **kwargs):
        super(ContrastiveLoss, self).__init__(weight, batch_axis, **kwargs)
        self.margin = margin

    def hybrid_forward(self, F, output1, output2, label):
        euclidean_distance = F.sqrt(F.square(output1 - output2))
        loss_contrastive = F.mean(((1-label) * F.square(euclidean_distance) +
                                      label * F.square(F.clip(self.margin - euclidean_distance, 0.0, 10))))
        return loss_contrastive


def aug_transform(data, label):
    augs = mx.image.CreateAugmenter(data_shape=(1, 100, 100))

    for aug in augs:
        data = aug(data)

    return data, label


def run_training():
    siamese_dataset = SiameseNetworkDataset(root=Config.training_dir,transform=aug_transform)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(siamese_dataset, shuffle=True, num_workers=1, batch_size=Config.train_batch_size)

    counter = []
    loss_history = []
    iteration_number = 0

    net = SiameseNetwork()
    net.initialize(init=mx.init.Xavier())
    trainer = Trainer(net.collect_params(), 'adam', {'learning_rate': 0.0005})
    loss = ContrastiveLoss(margin=2.0)

    for epoch in range(0, Config.train_number_epochs):
        for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader, 0):
            img0, img1, label = data

            with autograd.record():
                output1, output2 = net(img0, img1)
                loss_contrastive = loss(output1, output2, label)
                loss_contrastive.backward()

            trainer.step(Config.train_batch_size)

            if i % 10 == 0:
                print("Epoch number {}\n Current loss {}\n".format(epoch, loss_contrastive))
                iteration_number += 10
                counter.append(iteration_number)
                loss_history.append(loss_contrastive)

    #show_plot(counter, loss_history)
    return net


def run_predict(net):
    folder_dataset_test = SiameseNetworkDataset(root=Config.testing_dir,transform=aug_transform)
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(folder_dataset_test, shuffle=True, num_workers=1, batch_size=Config.train_batch_size)

    dataiter = iter(test_dataloader)
    x0, _, _ = next(dataiter)
    _, x1, label2 = next(dataiter)
    output1, output2 = net(x0, x1)
    euclidean_distance = mx.ndarray.sqrt(mx.ndarray.square(output1 - output2))
    print('x0 vs x1 dissimilarity is {}'.format(euclidean_distance[0][0]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = run_training()
    run_predict(net)
```